# Overlapping windows with transparency in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

Let's say I have a background window and a foreground window. **Is there a way for these to overlap so that an "empty character" on the foreground signifies transparency?** This means that it would display the background window on that character only.

I'm sure there are ways of implementing this myself. However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something like this already exists. If I'm using the wrong library altogether, please tell me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, curses won't do this for you (nor would any of the likely-suggested alternatives).  You could write an application using curses (or any of the *et cetera*) to do this, but that makes the question out of scope for Stack Overflow.